# Glide How to load a GIF from external storage using glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I have stored a gif in my external storage of android device. Now i want load the gif . But its doesnt loading the gif always coming as blank. How to resolve this

```
 Glide.with(context)
                        .load(Uri.fromFile("File Path"))
                        .asGif().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Have you tried the same with a jpeg?

Comment: yes its work jpeg

Comment: Gif is just not supported. Yoh should use a gif image class.